# Voting system and PHP session is not working

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-cookies, voting-system

I am developing a voting system in PHP with MySQL, in which user enter his choice through radio button and this will go in database. On same page, the percentage of user votes appears after clicking submit button.

But the code does not work for more then one time. Please help me to sort out this query.

## Further detail

In this program I use database table poll in which I make two columns named `yes` and `no` and set their value 0. Then, I use two variables `$i` and `$j` for updating the value of yes or no in database on click submit button.

If "yes" is selected then `$i` increments its value and using an `UPDATE` query it is saved. I then fetch the value from both yes and no columns to calculate percentage.

I set `$_session['yes']` to store the result of percentage of voters who voted "yes", and the same for the variable `$_session['no']`. Finally, I fetch values from database to store in `$i` and `$j` for next click, but the values are not changing.

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    $conn=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db('oop',$conn);
      global $i,$j; 
     if(isset($_POST['btnsav']) && isset($_POST['vote']))
      { if($_POST['vote']=='yes')
     {   $y=$i++;
    $query="update poll set yes='$y'";
    $res=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
            if($res>0)
            {
                $qry="select yes from poll";
                $res=mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
                $r=mysql_fetch_array($res) or die(mysql_error());
                $k=$r[0];

                $qry="select no from poll";
                $res=mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
                $r1=mysql_fetch_array($res) or die(mysql_error());
                $k1=$r1[0];

                $y=$k/($k+$k1);
                $y1=$y*100;
                $_SESSION['yes']=$y1;


            }

         }
               else 

         {
             $n=$j++;       
             $query="update poll set no='$n'";
             $res=mysql_query($query) or die($query);

            if($res>0)
            {

                $qry="select no from poll";
                $res=mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
                $r=mysql_fetch_array($res) or die(mysql_error());
                $k=$r[0];

                $qry="select yes from poll";
                $res=mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
                $r1=mysql_fetch_array($res) or die(mysql_error());
                $k1=$r1[0];

                $y=$k/($k+$k1);
                $y1=$y*100;
                $_SESSION['no']=$y1;


         }


          }
       }

                    $qry1="select yes from poll";
                $res1=mysql_query($qry1) or die(mysql_error());
                $r1=mysql_fetch_array($res1) or die(mysql_error());
                $i=$r1[0];

                 $qry2="select no from poll";
                $res2=mysql_query($qry2) or die(mysql_error());
                $r2=mysql_fetch_array($res2) or die(mysql_error());
                $j=$r2[0];
                   echo ceil($i);
                   echo ceil($j);
    ?>
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .main
            {
                margin-top: 50px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
        <center>
            <h2><font color="blue">Vote For India</font></h2>
        <form method="post">
            <tr>
                <td>Ques: Are you support Rahul Gandhi as PM candidate??<br /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>YES<input type="radio" name="vote" value="yes" /><br />
                NO<input type="radio" name="vote" value="no" /><br /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <input type="submit" name="btnsav" value="VOTE" /><br />
            </tr>
           <?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['yes']))
                {
                    echo ceil($_SESSION['yes']);
                }
                elseif (isset($_SESSION['no'])) 
                {
                   echo 'Non supportrs'.ceil($_SESSION['no']);
                }
                      ?>
        </form>
        </center>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php
ob_end_flush();
session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: The query `update poll set yes='$y'` will reset **all** `yes` columns to the specified value, but won't touch `no` columns (ah, and I see you have the same for `no` later on). Is that what you intended?

Comment: "Not working" isn't really a helpful problem description.  What *is* it doing?  What debugging have you done to narrow down the problem?  In what specific way does the code not behave as expected?  When you debug it, where do the runtime behavior and variable values differ from what you expect?  You have to put in at least *some* effort, Stack Overflow isn't a debugger.

Comment: It might be useful to edit into your question the algorithm you are using, or comment the code (the latter is probably best). As it stands, I can't work out what each step is meant to do.

Comment: adding to @halfer, Also, why is $y=$i++? What are you setting $y to and why?

Comment: thanks to all, in this program i use database table poll in which i make two colums named yes and no and set their value 0, then i use two variables $i and $j for updating the value of yes or no in database on click submit button. if yes select then $i increaments its value and through update query it table updates. and then fetch the value from both yes and no column to calculate percentage. but this all worked just once and now on click there is no change may be it is becose of session please help me to fix it.

Comment: This really calls for basic debugging. What exactly goes wrong where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of misunderstandings in this code, and a few things that are not exactly wrong but could do with improvement.

Firstly, there is no need to declare `global $i,$j` - outside of a function or method you are already in global context. I am wondering whether you intend these variables to be "for all users" i.e. every time someone clicks "yes", `$i` is incremented, and every time someone clicks "no", `$j` is incremented. Unfortunately it doesn't work like that - they will be zero for every run of the script (technically they will start off as uninitialised, and when you increment them they will emit a "variable undefined" notice, and will assume their original value to be zero).

Secondly, you don't need sessions for this program, unless you want to remember something on a per-user user basis, and where that data is not stored in the database. As far as I can tell the only thing you need to store on a per-user basis is their vote, and since that is stored in the database, there is nothing else to remember. (To be fair, you may wish to remember the user has voted, so you can thank them for voting and disable the voting buttons, but that is a weak protection against someone who is intent on voting more than once).

It is not clear what you are using `ob_start()` and `ob_flush()` for. I would suggest removing them.

Now, the reason people found your question hard to understand was that the data types of the columns had not been made clear. Normally, voting code stores a row per voter, so one can have *some* certainty that the votes are not dishonest. That would mean that the `yes` and `no` would be Booleans. However, I've worked out that you intend for there to be only one row, and these values are integer counts.

In that case, you need to do an `UPDATE` using the current value. Here is how to do it for yes:

```
UPDATE poll SET yes = yes + 1;
```

As I say, it would be better to redesign this, so each voter's choice is recorded - otherwise someone will vote many times in order to make their preferred candidate appear more popular than is the case.

Lastly, some general tips:

- Make your indentation accurate. It doesn't matter if you use spaces or tabs, but keep it consistent. Switch on invisible characters in your editor if it helps.
- Use meaningful variable names. Don't use `$qry` and `$res`, use `$query` and `$result`. Single letter names are alright for small loops, but not here - use variables that represent what you mean. You will not make a performance saving by having shorter variables.
- When things don't work as expected, run the code and examine the database. Put in `exit()` commands in intermediate places and examine your interim results. This is the essence of debugging - work out roughly where your problem is, and narrow it down until you find a source of a bad result.
- When asking questions about databases, offer the `CREATE TABLE` SQL in your question, so readers can see the data structure, and show some sample data too. That would have cleared up a lot of initial confusion.